# Problem with load_all by using the devtools in R

Tags: r, devtools

Package (under development): ACRER
computer: iMAC (OS X 10.15.7)
RStudio version: 1.4.1717 R version: 4.1.0
The package "ACRER" has a main script "Wageningen_SQLite_2020.R" and 4 functions (Run_Queries.R,Wcombinations.R,Wexpected_visit_duration.R and Wcrosstab.R with 4 sub functions:NGroup0.R, NGroup1.R,NGroup2.R, NGroup3.R and NGroup4.R) After running "load_all" on my package in RStudio with "devools" I got at the end some conflicts  with my own R functions (eg. NGroup0() masks NGroup0()) followed with the following question: Did you accidentally source a file rather than using load_all()? (see reprex code bellow). I have used devtools for load_all and this question has no sense in my opinion at all. I will appreciate if somebody can make clear to me about this subject.

```r
devtools::load_all(path = "/Volumes/Aias/ACRER", reset = TRUE, 
    export_all = TRUE, helpers = TRUE, quiet = FALSE)
#> ℹ Loading ACRER
#> Loading required package: usethis
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Google's Terms of Service: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/.
#> Please cite ggmap if you use it! See citation("ggmap") for details.
#> Loading required package: proto
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'kableExtra'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:flextable':
#> 
#>     as_image, footnote
#> Loading required package: mice
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mice'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     cbind, rbind
#> * miceadds 3.11-6 (2021-01-21 11:48:47)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pkgload'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:devtools':
#> 
#>     has_tests, load_all, package_file
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pander'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:htmltools':
#> 
#>     p
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pracma'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:doBy':
#> 
#>     taylor
#> The following object is masked from 'SciViews:TempEnv':
#> 
#>     Fix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'reshape2'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     dcast, melt
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'testthat'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     matches
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     is_null
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     matches
#> The following object is masked from 'package:devtools':
#> 
#>     test_file
#> Wcrosstab(Rmatrix = RmatrixA, Cmatrix = CmatrixA, C1 = C1A)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'activity_pattern'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Wcrosstab(Rmatrix = RmatrixB, Cmatrix = CmatrixB, C1 = C1B)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'groupsRecr_act_ts'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Warning in xtfrm.data.frame(x): cannot xtfrm data frames
#> Wcrosstab(Rmatrix = RmatrixC, Cmatrix = CmatrixC, C1 = C1C)
#>      choicenr choicetxt                                        
#> [1,] "1"      "Pivot table for the number of persons"          
#> [2,] "2"      "Pivot tables for the expected visiting duration"
#> [3,] "3"      "Save tables in csv format files"                
#> [4,] "4"      "Exit"                                           
#>    RecrID                   recreation_areas
#> 1       1           Beeldengalerij Het Depot
#> 2       2                 Arboretum Belmonte
#> 3       3         Wageningen Berg en Bergpad
#> 4       4               Arboretum de Dreijen
#> 5       5              Uitwaarden Wageningen
#> 6       6                    Renkums Beekdal
#> 7       7     Utrechtse Heuvelrug_Grebbeberg
#> 8       8                    De Blauwe Kamer
#> 9       9        Ouwehands Dierenpark Rhenen
#> 10     10                  Kasteel Doorwerth
#> 11     11                          Edese bos
#> 12     12        AIRBORNE MUSEUM HARTENSTEIN
#> 13     13            Peppelenburg Westerrode
#> 14     14                   Landgoed Kernhem
#> 15     15                     Wekeromse Zand
#> 16     16                          De Betuwe
#> 17     17                             Roekel
#> 18     18         Hoog en Laag Amerongse Bos
#> 19     19                       Noord Ginkel
#> 20     20              Amerongse Bovenpolder
#> 21     21                 Lunters Buurtbosch
#> 22     22                          WARNSBORN
#> 23     23                     PARK ZYPENDAAL
#> 24     24                        Zuid Ginkel
#> 25     25  HET NATIONALE PARK DE HOGE VELUWE
#> 26     26                        BURGERS ZOO
#> 27     27                      PARK SONSBEEK
#> 28     28     HET NEDERLANDS OPENLUCHTMUSEUM
#> 29     29                  PARK ANGERENSTEIN
#> 30     30          PARK EN KASTEEL ROSENDAEL
#> 31     31 Nationaal Park_Utrechtse Heuvelrug
#> 32     32                    GROESBEEKSE BOS
#> 33     33          VELUWETRANSFERIUM POSBANK
#>   transport_type_ID transport_type_definition maximum_of_total_time
#> 1                 1                   on foot                    60
#> 2                 2                   bicycle                    50
#> 3                 3                       car                    40
#>   wait_time_per_full_travel minimum_distance_used maximum_distance_used
#> 1                         0                     0                     0
#> 2                         0                     0                    25
#> 3                         0                     0                   100
#>   speed_of_transport_type fixed_costs_per_transport_type
#> 1                       0                              0
#> 2                      20                              0
#> 3                      60                              0
#>   per_km_costs_per_transport_type per_person_costs_per_transport_type
#> 1                            0.00                                   0
#> 2                            0.00                                   0
#> 3                            0.65                                   0
#>   per_km_en_per_person_costs_per_transport_type
#> 1                                             0
#> 2                                             0
#> 3                                             0
#> Warning: 
#> ── Conflicts ──────────────────────────────────────────────── ACRER conflicts ──
#> x NGroup0() masks ACRER::NGroup0()
#> x NGroup1() masks ACRER::NGroup1()
#> x NGroup2() masks ACRER::NGroup2()
#> … and 7 more
#> 
#> Did you accidentally source a file rather than using `load_all()`?
#> Run `rm(list = c("NGroup0", "NGroup1", "NGroup2", "NGroup3", "NGroup4", "Run_Queries", "Wcombinations", "Wcrosstab", "Wexpected_visit_duration", "WInstallPackages"))` to remove the conflicts.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Restart R and try again. I usually get this message during pkg dev when I accidentally sourced one of my files.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. Sometimes it's okay to *delete* the previous question and ask again *with more/better detail*, but when there is no change in content then it seems like all you're doing is trying to keep your question at the top of the list, which is discouraged behavior (especially within 2 hours). (It's possible your questions will be downvoted by some if they believe you are manipulating that part of the system, though I think that's perhaps harsh in one-off repostings.)

Comment: If I am mistaken, please help me understand how this question is different/better than the other question; in that case, please ping me and I can reopen this question (and you will likely need to delete the previous question).